# How does fckeditor(grails plugin) store images?

Tags: grails, fckeditor

I started to learn grails and now I am trying to develop a simple blog.
I created the domain model(User, Tag, Comment, Category, Post), controllers.
I installed fckeditor plugin(for adding new posts). I want to add ui interface, which will be support wysiwyg editor. 
But I do not understand how does fckeditor store images, which will be linked to post. 
Advice please some links or code samples.

Answer (score 0):

... the editor stores the images in a folder that you need to specify. If I remember correctly it will insert the photo at point of cursor in the editor panel. There's another way to deal with it also. Upload your images/create thumbnails and where you have the thumbnails displayed on the page (say as links to full blown pixes) drag one onto the fckeditor pane and it will drop the thumbnail/link at cursor.

I'm sure you've been [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.9%20Uploading%20Files) as well ;-)